# AngularJS: show/hide multiple divs by evaluating their attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a number of divs in a loop:

```
<div ng-controller='PhotoController'>
  <div ng-repeat="photo in photos" ng-show='isShowImage'>
     <img ng-src ='{{photo.src}}' data-show='yes'>
     <br/>
 </div>
</div>
```

The line `<img ng-src ='{{photo.src}}' data-show='yes'>` can have `data-show` values as yes or no.

My controller is like:

```
app.controller("PhotoController",function($scope)
{
    $scope.isShowImage = true; //
});
```

By default all the photos are shown. When a button is clicked I want to evaluate the `data-show` property of each image and hide it if the property says `no`

The data-show attribute is a value that comes from database. It will always be either yes or no for an image. I will have a button called 'Show All' and another called 'Show Filtered'. 'Show Filtered' click should hide the photos where data-show is no

I am not sure how to do this...any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching something like this:

```
<body ng-app="ngToggle">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <button ng-click="toggleCustom()">Custom</button>
        <span ng-hide="custom">From:
            <input type="text" id="from" />
        </span>
        <span ng-hide="custom">To:
            <input type="text" id="to" />
        </span>
        <span ng-show="custom"></span>
    </div>
</body>

angular.module('ngToggle', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.custom = true;
        $scope.toggleCustom = function() {
            $scope.custom = $scope.custom === false ? true: false;
        };
}]);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geniuscarrier/tKZjZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PhotoController">
    <button ng-click="checkImg()">Check state</button>
    <div class="myImg" ng-repeat="photo in photos" ng-show='isShowImage'>
        <img ng-src ='{{photo.src}}' data-show='photo.state' ng-show="photo.visible">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('PhotoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.isShowImage = true;
    $scope.photos = [
        {src: "img1", state: "yes", visible: true},
        {src: "img2", state: "no", visible: true},
        {src: "img3", state: "yes", visible: true},
    ];
    $scope.checkImg = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i<$scope.photos.length; i++) {
            if($scope.photos[i].state == "no") $scope.photos[i].visible = false;
        }
    }
  }]);
```